# Average geometric efficiency in Positron Emission Tomography

Tags: medical-physics

While researching for my thesis I am using the book *"Physics in Nuclear Medicine"* by Simon R. Cherry, James A. Sorenson and Michael E. Phelps. In Chapter 18.8 they talk about the average geometric efficiency, luckily the content I am referring to can also be found on [this website](https://radiologykey.com/positron-emission-tomography/). They calculate the average geometrical efficiency with

$$
\bar{g}_{ACD} = \frac{1}{3} \cdot \frac{2 \cdot A_{det}}{\pi D^2}.
$$

Where D is the distance between the detector pairs, $2 \cdot A_{det}$ is the area of the detectors and $\frac{1}{3}$ is the factor for averaging the efficiency. The formula is basically the solid angle from the center of the detector ring (or the two detectors) and the Area of the detector is multiplied by two because coincidence detector involves two detectors. Now, I understand that this is only true for a point source at the center of the ring and therefore the average should be used as an estimation which considers the whole field of view. But I can't seem to figure out how they have come up with the factor of $\frac{1}{3}$. They say it is *"the average height of a pyramid"* but how does this relate to the average geometric efficiency? A little note on the side, the equation above is only true if the distance to the detector is large compared to the size of the detector.